# R: How to get something like adjacency matrix, but on the intersection value of third column?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2, adjacency-matrix

I have data frame like this:

```
      V1     V2     LABEL
    1 83965 891552   A
    2 88599 891552   B
    3 42966 891552   C
    4 83965 891553   D
    5 88599 891553   D
    6 42966 891553   B
```

How can I convert it to something like adjacency matrix, but on the intersection of colum-row i would like to have, the third colum value, like that:

```
        891552 891553
  42966      C      B
  83965      A      D
  88599      B      D
```

@Henrik

I got such error. I think this segmentfault is caused by big size of data.

```
Using label as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7fff1e099a90, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("split_indices", group, as.integer(n))
 2: split_indices(.group, .n)
 3: vaggregate(.value = value, .group = overall, .fun = fun.aggregate,     ..., .default = fill, .n = n)
 4: cast(data, formula, fun.aggregate, ..., subset = subset, fill = fill,     drop = drop, value.var = value.var)
 5: dcast(dat, item ~ worker)
Any idead how it is possible to get rid of it?
```

### I gave up trys with R and I used Python, because all of the solutions: tapply,dcast, reshape, cast were performing extremly poor causing whole system hangs for hours.

## BUT: if you know some solutions, which can proceed in a effective way with huge data, let me know

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reshape data from long to wide format R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r)

Comment: @andi did you use `tapply` on a `data.table` or a `data.frame`? It should run VERY quickly on a `data.table`. Please show your code and the `str( yourdataframename )`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the first sentence says that the asker is no longer interested in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this, where `df` is your data frame:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, V1 ~ V2)

#      V1 891552 891553
# 1 42966      C      B
# 2 83965      A      D
# 3 88599      B      D
```

Comment: cool, but not for a case of 639k rows. Some suggestions, how to deal with big data?

Comment: @andi you should have mentioned that in the OP! -1 for that (and +1 for Henrik).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `data.table` package. You can actually do this kind of reshaping in `base` R using `tapply`. This should be fast as it operates on a `data.table`...

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
tapply(DT$LABEL , list(DT$V1,DT$V2) , as.character )

#      891552 891553
#42966 "C"    "B"   
#83965 "A"    "D"   
#88599 "B"    "D"
```

Hopefully that will be fast.

Comment: tapply reshaping - cool! +1!

Comment: @Henrik thanks. I don't use it often, I find it hard to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @andi why the accept and then un-accept. What else would you like to know? or how was this solution not acceptable? Perhaps you want a data.frame returned over a matrix?

Comment: @andi, I don't find it very appropriate to change the premise of a question after people have spent their time trying to help you. It can be very frustrating trying to answer 'moving target' questions. Please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.